# HTML post selected value in checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new to PHP and its development. I used html checkboxes. I want to save all the checked values there. In order to do that I'm retrieving id of the selected checkboxes. But my alert not retrieve the value I expected. I would be very grateful if anyone could point out my stupidity. Thanks!

I would be very grateful if anyone could point out my stupidity. Thanks!

```
<html> 
    <head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function OnChangeCheckbox (checkbox) {
            if (checkbox.checked) {

                var inputElements = document.getElementsBy('tagbox');
                 alert ('checkbox');
            }
            else {
                alert ("The check box is not checked.");
            }


      }


 </script>

    </head>


<?php
foreach ($relevanttags as $tags) {

    echo "<br>";
    echo '<input class="tagbox"  type="checkbox" onclick="OnChangeCheckbox (this)"  value="' . $tags . '" name="tags" >' . $tags;
    echo "</br>";
}
?>


</html>
```

Comment: maybe remove the space: OnChangeCheckbox(this)

Comment: @Nitsan Baleli i removed it but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsBy('tagbox');
```

has some flaws:

first, `getElementsBy` is not a function. What you probably mean is `getElementsById`

second, it won't work anyway since your checkboxes don't have an Id.

As you are using jQuery, you may try this:

```
function OnChangeCheckbox (checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
             alert ('checkbox');
        }
        else {
            alert ("The check box is not checked.");
        }

        // look for all elements of class "tagbox"
        $('.tagbox').each(function (i, e) {
                // e is the checkbox, i is the loop index
                if ( e.checked )
                      alert ('checkbox no. ' + i + ' is checked');
        });

  }
```

etc.

Comment: here i want, print the values of checked checkboxes could you please help me to do that

Comment: Made a mistake, the parameters to the callback are quite the other way round, made a change above, mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var selected = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("input:checkbox[name=tags]:checked").each(function() {
           selected.push($(this).val());
        });

    });
```

Comment: Why use new Array() ? just use Array literal .. myVar = []

Comment: @Jivani Jaydeep thank you dude. i have vote up your answer. but second answer is well suits for my question. so i accept it. thanks dude. this will help me when i use js arrays.thank you again